# Why do I get Soap exception?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, soap

I am trying to upload an attachment to a list:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ConsoleApplication3.TestReference;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string srcUrl = @"C:......comp_name.xlsx";
            FileStream fStream = File.OpenRead(srcUrl);
            string fileName = fStream.Name.Substring(3);
            byte[] contents = new byte[fStream.Length];
            fStream.Read(contents, 0, (int)fStream.Length);
            fStream.Close();

            ServiceWebReference.Lists listService = new ServiceWebReference.Lists();
            listService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

            try
            {
                // adding attachment
                string result = listService.AddAttachment("testList", "1", fileName, contents);
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
            catch (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.GetBaseException());
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get `Unhandled SOAP exception ...`.
Here is the full exception that I got:

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
  at ConsoleApplication3.ServiceWebReference.Lists.AddAttachment(String listName, String listItemID, String fileName, Byte[] attachment) 
    in z:\Xxxxl\TestC\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\Web References\ServiceWebReference\Reference.cs:line 782
  at ConsoleApplication3.Program.Main(String[] args) 
    in z:\Xxxxl\TestC\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\Program.cs:line 29

Press any key to continue . . .
```

I added the reference correctly: `http  ..... /_vti_bin/lists.asmx`

How can I debug it? What is the SOAP exception in my case?

Comment: You have to tell _us_ what the `SoapException` is. What's the full exception? Please post it in your question.

Comment: @John Saunders Thank You for response .  I have posted exception

Comment: I'm surprised it didn't say more, but `SoapException` means that the server returned an error. It may or may not have also returned you a "SOAP Fault", which might have included additional information. You should do: `try {... your code ... } catch (SoapException ex){... here you can look at the details of the exception ...}`

Comment: Sorry for a silly question . How can I add reference to `SoapException`. I am a noob and I used to work only with Java, and all i needed to do is to `import` a certain exception. How do I `import` `SoapException` here ? I got a message :  `namespace Soap Exception not found `

Comment: Try `catch (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException ex)`

Comment: Thank you. I have added `Console.WriteLine(e.GetBaseException());
            Console.WriteLine(e);` to my code. Is it the right way ? i have posted the result to my question

Comment: No. Just `Console.WriteLine(e);` You may also wantto set a breakpoint at the `Console.WriteLine`, and look at the contents of `e` in the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `catch (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException e)`

1.Use ex instead e, because e already exists as `EventArgs e`
2.Try `catch (SoapException ex)` It's a better way

So, concentrete to the Exception handling buddy,
I hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you +1 . If I use `catch (SoapException ex)` , then Visual Studio highlights this and does not compile . What reference library should  I add so that it does not underline in red `catch (SoapException ex)` ?  John Saunders recommended that I use `catch (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException e)`

Comment: You should browse and add System.Web.Protocols library, and then the catch (SoapException ex), you can add references, you know, add it as your class library on the top